# Passing data to index.html

Tags: angular, parameter-passing

I need to pass the value of user token in index.html from app.component.ts. 
I have a script code in the index.html file where I 'll be needing user token.

Is there any way I can achieve this functionality (or any other way where I can add my script tag to pass the value of user token)?

Here is the script:

```
<script>
 window.fcWidget.init({
 "config": {
  "cssNames": {
    "widget": "custom_fc_frame"
  }
 },
 "host": "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
 "token": "enter token here"
 });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate with more detail? Do you want to store user token anywhere?

Comment: Can you show your script? Or how it works/expects and how you call it?

Comment: Please find below the script.


`<script>
 window.fcWidget.init({
  "config": {
     "cssNames": {
        "widget": "custom_fc_frame"
     }
  },
  "host": "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
  "token": "user token"
 });
</script>`

This script has been added in Index.html
I just need to pass the user token which I have in my app.component.ts to this script. 

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks for looking into this issue.